# Guidelines for preventing HTML injection

Tags: phishing, injection, websites

We have a tell-a-friend feature on our website where we present a form to the user for recipient email and personal message. The personal message is added to our email template. The email is sent on behalf of our website. Our form looks like this

[image]

**What checks should we make to ensure that an malicious person cannot hack it and use it for its own/something else's publicity?**

Recently, we had a case of email fraud where a malicious user was able to inject some html code in the input box provided for typing personal message. The received email contained a totally new email template (and our template at the bottom) and HTTP links to other sites.

Please add to the below points

1. Regex check for URLs and do-not-send URLs
2. ?

Comment: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: I have updated the question

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple (in theory):

- Always escape user-provided input
- Always do your escaping at display time. This prevents issues where you've escaped something for the wrong content type, and allows you to plug discovered holes without having to write a migration for old data.

Comment: Escape user-provided input (escape how?) Or do you mean HTML encode? Also, I didn't get your second point completely.

Comment: @ShwetabhShekhar The escaping method will depend on your display medium; for html it'll be html encoding, for json it'll be json encoding, for urls it'd be url encoding, etc.

Comment: What part don't you understand about my second point?

Answer (score 0):

Very vague question, but if you want a sure fire way to keep gmail from displaying the text inputed in the message box as html, you can change the content type from html to just plain text.  If this is what you are looking for I can elaborate.

Comment: I have updated the question